# Use both rewrite and php-fpm for .php extension in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to migrate to `Nginx + PHP-FPM` from `Apache + mod_php`. I am currently using `mod_rewrite` to rewrite some virtual URIs ending in `.php` to actual PHP scripts. This works perfectly when using `mod_php`. But with with `Nginx + FPM`, since we have to use `proxy_pass`, this is not working. When I add a regex location block to match `.php` extension, it gets highest precedence, and my rewrite rules are not applied.

How can I resolve this?

```
location /test/ {
    rewrite "^/test/([a-z]+).php$" test.php?q=$1 last; 
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    set $fastcgi_script_name_custom $fastcgi_script_name;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        set $fastcgi_script_name_custom "/cms/index.php";
    }

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the `rewrite` rule above your `location` blocks within the context of the `server` block. Or you can place the `rewrite` rule within the `location` block that matches the URI.

So you can use either this:

```
rewrite "^/test/([a-z]+).php$" /test.php?q=$1 last;

location / { ... }

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { ... }
```

Or this:

```
location / { ... }

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    rewrite "^/test/([a-z]+).php$" /test.php?q=$1 break;
    ...
}
```

Notice that the rewritten URI needs a leading `/` (unlike Apache convention).

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.